# Pass locals from controller to active model serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

I am trying to pass locals(prod: @product.id) to AMS in my controller, as follows:

```
@options_json = ActiveModel::SerializableResource.new(@option_types, prod: @product.id)
@options_json = @options_json.to_json(serialization_context: ActiveModelSerializers::SerializationContext.new(request), serialization_options: {prod: @product.id})
```

I am not sure whether to pass it during initialization or during call to `to_json`. Moreover I am unable to read this passed param in my `OptionTypeSerializer`. I've tried using `options[:prod]`, `serialization_options[:prod]`, `serialization_opts[:prod]` and a few different solutions that I found on stackoverflow, but none worked.
My AMS is pointed to master and in my `gemfile.lock` AMS version is `active_model_serializers (0.10.0.rc5)`

Also tried using:

```
@options_json = ActiveModel::SerializableResource.new(@option_types, serialization_context: ActiveModelSerializers::SerializationContext.new(request), prod: @product.id).to_json
```

but getting the value of `instance_options[:prod]` as null, although it is not null

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I need to pass options into a serializer I do something like this:

```
# Controller
class CatalogPagesController < ApplicationController

  # GET /catalog_pages/event/:id
  def event
    @catalog_pages = @event.catalog_pages
    render json: @catalog_pages, index: true, each_serializer: Adm::CatalogPageSerializer
  end
end

# Serializer
class CatalogPageSerializer < Adm::FormSerializer
  attributes :id, :body, :catalog_page_templates

  def include_catalog_page_templates?
    return true unless @options[:index].present?
  end
end
```

In this example I want to conditionally not return certain elements of JSON when coming from the index route.

Comment: it leads to `undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass` for @options[:prod]

Comment: I'm using this version of the gem. `gem 'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.8.3'`. Maybe options have changed since then?